# a proper verb that describe the formation of Taylor cone in polymer science

Tags: word-choice, technical

In polymer science, to form a core-shell nanofiber using electrospinning process, two separate solutions(i.e., core solution and shell solution) are injected to a capillary tube and .....
in order to form the core-shell structure, a regular Taylor cone is needed to be shaped which involves both solutions, and this is not feasible, unless the viscosity of the shell solution is high enough.
Now, I do not know what is the proper verb that best describes mixing of both solutions, for example here:
Ex: Therefore, the core solution could not "mix", "accommodate", "join", "solve" with the shell solution, and thus the core solution start dripping.
Which one is the most appropriate?? Accommodate, mix, join, solve,..........

Comment: 'come into contact with'?

Comment: I suspect you will get a knowledgeable answer on another site. Is this a physics question, or a chemistry question? (Note: this question can be migrated. Please don't just repeat it somewhere else.)

Comment: I recommend *eduction*. As others have noted, it isn't about mixing, it's just a case of the surface area being increased in the jet to the extent that all the fluid is in  contact. Eduction is the engineering term that describes the process of jet formation. "Therefore the core solution was not educted with the shell solution. (We normally use educted as the past tense, not educed).

Comment: I think from a chemistry perspective, you are making a mixture, so the verb would be *mixing?*

Answer (score 2):

I simply googled ***formation of Taylor cone in polymer science*** and got this:

> "...this causes dripping of the two solutions followed by an
> intermittent jet from the sheath with an occasional **incorporation**
> of the core."
>
> https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/taylor-cone

I have no idea what a Taylor cone is but I suggest that this is a suitable way to discover the usual terminology. Another way is to use [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=formation+of+Taylor+cone+in+polymer+science&btnG=) with a well-crafted search term.

Answer (score 1):

The core solution and shell solution are **combined**. They combine through contact and are coaxially ejected. (I don't believe they are actively mixed, so to speak of mixing would be somewhat misleading.)

If the two solutions don't **suitably adhere** or aren't **effectively joined** or if the less viscous core solution isn't successfully **entrained with** or **attached to** or **integrated with** or **encapsulated by** or **supported by** the more viscous shell solution, then the former might detach and drip.

(Note that these individual descriptions—a lack of adhesion, a lack of entrainment, a lack of encapsulation—describe different defect modes; select the one that best fits your intended meaning. Most broadly, you can say that they **don't usefully combine**.)

In that case, the shell solution, apparatus, and/or procedure **cannot accommodate** that particular core solution.

Answer (score 0):

...a regular Taylor cone must *form* from the two solutions,

Therefore, the core solution *failed to resolve* with the shell solution to form a Taylor cone. As a result the core solution started dripping.